# Shortcuts - Run Shell Script - error with unix socket

Tags: command-line, shortcuts-app

### Issue:

Shortcuts app can't seem to talk directly to a unix socket.  I get this error, "**Error: Custom { kind: NotFound, error: "no socket found" }**"
when configured to execute:

```
/usr/local/bin/alacritty --socket $(lsof -U | awk '/^alacritty.*var\/folders/ {print $NF}') msg create-window
```

However, if I spawn a subprocess to execute the command, everything works fine; the process on the other end of the socket responds as expected.  Using `ps` I can see that my new alacritty window is a child process of the PID listening on the other end of the socket.

### What works:

I'm using MacOS Shortcuts app to **RunShellScript** (in bash) of:

```
/usr/local/bin/alacritty -e /usr/local/bin/alacritty-new-window
```

where `alacritty-new-window` is:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/bash

# use `head` to find first;  otherwise, might see the intermediate shortcuts process
# i.e. avoid: /var/folders/7q/ktkg02v12sg111x1kqtbsg2w0000gp/T/com.apple.shortcuts.mac-helper//Alacritty-40370.sock
ALACRITTY_SOCKET=$(lsof -U | awk '/^alacritty.*var\/folders/ {print $NF}' | head -1)
echo ${ALACRITTY_SOCKET}
/usr/local/bin/alacritty --socket ${ALACRITTY_SOCKET} msg create-window
```

### Troubleshooting:

If I have the **RunShellScript** just echo the socket (i.e. `echo $(lsof -U | awk '/^alacritty.*var\/folders/ {print $NF}')`, ths gives me the expected output of:
`/var/folders/7q/ktkg02v12sg111x1kqtbsg2w0000gp/T/Alacritty-16780.sock`

If I change the **RunShellScript** to `ls $(lsof -U | awk '/^alacritty.*var\/folders/ {print $NF}')` I see the socket I want:

```
srwxr-xr-x  1 user  staff  0 Feb 18 22:59 /var/folders/7q/ktkg02v12sg111x1kqtbsg2w0000gp/T/Alacritty-16780.sock
```

checking with a quick `whoami`, Shortcuts finds my user name.

So, I can see the socket.  I'm the owner of the socket.

I changed **System Settings**->**Privacy & Security**->**Full Disk Access** enabling access for both Shortcuts and Finder, but there was no perceptible effect; I got the same error.

For completeness, I tried an alternate executor (bash instead of alacritty) with `/usr/local/bin/bash -c /usr/local/bin/alacritty-new-window`, and still had the error.

### TL;DR

using Shortcuts, I can see a unix socket.  A subprocess can use that socket, but Shortcuts itself gets a socket error.

Can anyone help me understand what's going on?